# How to use different CSS file in child of react route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I just started learning REACT, but I have a problem with **`React-route`**, problem is children use parent CSS, but how can we use fresh new CSS on child? Not anything get from parent CSS?

I have a file structure like this:

```
---src
-----index.js
-----login.js
-----home.js
-----style.css
```

I imported 'style.css' in login.js but it continute to use in login.js, I want to design complete different style in `home.js`, so I created home.css and put some element in there but it not cast over the style.css.
Here is some of my code

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from './login.js'
import New from './home.js'
const routing = (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/new" component={New} />
        </div>
    </Router>
  );
ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

my login.js
problem is style.css have a `body` element that I can't change, if use a `div` in `login.js` and put a `className` it have background but have border, not full page.So I load localhost:3000/new it still have same background, I want it totally white, like fresh page or have dirrent CSS, not use parent.
So my question is:

**How to make each child in route have unique style, not have it from it parent?
or how can I do that with React?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS not changing when using React Router to route to another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59418570/css-not-changing-when-using-react-router-to-route-to-another-component)

Answer (score 0):

You can use many different approach to styling a react app like css-in-js, css modules, tailwindcss,...
I recommend use css modules because is not effect on app performance (zero run-time).
To apply css modules in your project must config [webpack css loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) ([CRA support](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) out of the box).

Comment: thank you so much,so use css loader we can get rid of using parent style, right?

Comment: Yes when using css modules each class names scoped locally and you can use css class like js moules.  At compile time hashed class name .

Comment: If my answer is complete and correct please endorse me.

Comment: i still reseach for css loader but when i get it by npm i don't see webpack.config.js? how can i use this with my css

Comment: Are you using Create React App?

Comment: yes, i create-react-app, but my problem is, i my style.css use for login page, and it  located in localhost:3000 ,and css use for home too, so i want to get rid of this, my home is localhost:3000/home it also have same css as localhost:3000, how can we stop this thing? please help, i do it for my final exam in collage,thank you so much

Comment: It is simple you not need config `css loader` if using create-react-app. you must rename `style.css` to `style.module.css` and use css as a module file. for more detail please read this [doc](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/). If not solved your problem please [contact me](https://t.me/masihjahangiri).

Comment: hey sir, do you have discord, please help me